# How to install fonts on centos7.2, fc-cache command is not recognized

Tags: fonts, centos

On CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) I want to install fonts.
I already did that on another machine using the
 fc-cache and fc-list command but on this new machine these commands are not recognized.
What package do I need to install to get these commands?

---

I have the Arial fonts in
**/usr/share/fonts/Arial**

And a Python matplotlib code for testing that tries to use the font.

Note that
Package **fontconfig-2.10.95-7.el7.x86_64** already installed and latest version.

**I had to delete**:
/home/centos/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache

To fix the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to install font for current user, you need to make `.fonts` directory in your own home directory `~`. For example `mkdir ~/.fonts` .

If you want to install fonts and be accessible by all users, you have to copy your standard fonts into `/usr/share/fonts` directory.

Comment: I've already done that but don't I need to run fc-cache?

Comment: If you use a specific application (Libreoffice, etc) just restart it and you will see recently installed fonts in your fonts list in that application.

Comment: Yes, matplotlib is a special case. Its text support is rather hacky, you often need to remove its cache manually. Matplotlib sort of uses fontconfig like a normal linux app but the fontconfig support is partial (does not use the fontconfig API and library calls and tries to emulate them by massaging fontconfig CLI utilities output. It's quite a wreck be prepared for loads of pain each time you'll try to change font settings in your code)

Answer (score 2):

Linux font management is done by fontconfig

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/